# OpenBSD's sh: shebang is not being used

Tags: ksh, openbsd

I have three scripts, two of them are used as a shebang

- `shebang-1`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "#1"
exec sh -- "$@"
```

- `shebang-2` which uses `shebang-1`

```
#!/home/a/ex/shebang-1
echo "#2"
exec sh -- "$@"
```

- `script`

```
#!/home/a/ex/shebang-2
echo script...
```

When I execute `script`, I expect

```
#1
#2
script...
```

instead I get only

```
$ ./script 
script...
```

Calling them explicitly works,

```
$ ./shebang-1 ./shebang-2 ./script
#1
#2
script...
```

Files have the following permissions

```
$ ls -l
total 24
-rwx------  1 a  a  38 Sep  3 18:00 script*
-rwx------  1 a  a  38 Sep  3 18:05 shebang-1*
-rwx------  1 a  a  50 Sep  3 18:05 shebang-2*
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: how exactly do you execute the script when you get the wrong result?

Comment: @ilkkachu Clarified this, all files are executable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenBSD does not support interpreters which are themselves shebanged scripts in shebangs. The interpreters have to be actual binaries.

Trying to execute your `script` fails with `ENOEXEC` and the shell falls back to running `/bin/sh` with the script as the first argument, as documented.

You can check that by trying to run your script directly via `execve(2)`, not via the shell, perl's `exec`, `xargs(1)`, `env(1)`, `execvp(3)` or some other wrapper which emulates the shell's behaviour.

If this is not documented, you can just look at the [source code](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/e4c12d7a863e1916b1a171487174679e25ab965c/sys/kern/exec_script.c#L80).

Anyways, OpenBSD is like most other systems except Linux; AFAIK only Linux seems to support other scripts as interpreters, up to a limit of 4 levels, after which the `execve` will fail with `ELOOP`.